# Binding combobox selected value to property

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I have an **Enum Animals** with Fish and Cat values inside.

```
public ObservableCollection<AnimalsEnum> Animals { get; set; }
```

I bind the enum to be shown in a combobox.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Animals }">
```

I have also property called **AnimalsChanged** of the type AnimalsEnum

When I choose an animal from the the combobox, I want a property called **AnimalsChanged** to get the value of the enum from the combobox.

How do I do it from the xaml ? Any Idea

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `SelectedItem` to bind the actual data item from the list. With `SelectedValue` you can bind a specific property from the `SelectedItem`. It binds two way by default so you don't need to specify that:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Animals }" SelectedItem="{Binding AnimalsChanged}">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Appriciate it.